# Is it possible to add 2 values to 2 variables in one line?

Tags: python

Is it possible to add multiple values to multiple variables in one line?

Kind of similar to this:
`a,b = (0,0)`
But more like:
`a,b += (1,2)`
I know you can add them separately but I was wondering if there was a clean way to just do it one line.

Comment: if you have any significant amount of math to do, consider handling them as an array of values like NumPy will do for you!

Comment: You could probably do something like `a, b = a+1, b+2`?

Comment: `a += 1; b += 2`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. As per 7.2.1. [Augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)

> An augmented assignment evaluates the target (**which, unlike normal
> assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking**) and the expression
> list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment
> on the two operands, and assigns the result to the original target.
> The target is only evaluated once.
>
> An augmented assignment expression like `x += 1` can be rewritten as `x = x + 1` to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect. In the
> augmented version, x is only evaluated once. Also, when possible, the
> actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than
> creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object
> is modified instead.
>
> Unlike normal assignments, augmented assignments evaluate the
> left-hand side before evaluating the right-hand side. For example,
> `a[i] += f(x)` first looks-up `a[i]`, then it evaluates `f(x)` and performs
> the addition, and lastly, it writes the result back to `a[i]`.
>
> **With the exception of assigning to tuples and multiple targets in a
> single statement, the assignment done by augmented assignment
> statements is handled the same way as normal assignments**. Similarly,
> with the exception of the possible in-place behavior, the binary
> operation performed by augmented assignment is the same as the normal
> binary operations.
>
> For targets which are attribute references, the same caveat about
> class and instance attributes applies as for regular assignments.

For this case, the simplest way is to perform two statements:

```
a, b = 0, 0
a += 1
b += 2
```

You could also create a new tuple and do a normal unpacking assignment.

```
a, b = 0, 0
a, b = a + 1, b + 2
```

Or use a container that wraps the elements and supports an overriden augment assignment operators, such as numpy.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 0])
a += np.array([1, 2])
```